# song liked by user the most in a given month and year

Tags: sql, hive

I am trying to find the top first heard song by a user in a given month of a year

I am using the following data

```
user-id       date           song
.......      .......        ......
1           2017-9-30        song1
1           2017-9-10        song1
1           2017-3-12        song2
1           2017-9-01        song1
1           2017-12-31       song1
1           2017-09-12       song3
1           2017-10-11       song1
1           2017-09-09       song5
1           2017-10-08       song4
2           2017-07-12       song1
2           2017-12-31       song3
2           2017-10-12       song5
3           2017-10-11       song1
3           2017-10-09       song7
3           2017-10-08       song2
3           2017-07-12       song2
```

I am trying to get the following output

```
   user-id     year       month       song     count
   .......    ......      ......      .....    ......
      1        2017        9          song1       3
```

I have tried the following query,but i am getting all the data in descending order and i am unable to pick the top most data

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS year, MONTH(date) AS month,song,count(song) c
FROM table where id=1 and year(dt)=2017 and month(dt)=9
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) ,song ORDER BY c DESC
```

I have even tried using

```
SELECT d.*
FROM (SELECT id,year(date) y,month(date) m,count(song) as c,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY month(date) ORDER BY COUNT(song) DESC) as seqnum
     FROM table where id=1 and month(date)=9
     GROUP BY month(date),year(date) song 
    ) d
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY c, dt DESC ;
```

And it throws error as

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 5:37 extraneous input 'song' expecting ) near ''

Comment: 2nd query is missing a comma after year(date) in subquery group by.  (just addressing the error, not the results.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`LIMIT`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select):

```
SELECT YEAR(date) AS year, MONTH(date) AS month,song,count(song) c
FROM table 
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) ,song 
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 1
```